# when I select many row of table and insert breakpoint dont show my list correctly?

Tags: list, select, model-view-controller

[image: screen shot reference]

when I trace code don't show city list correctly

how I can fix it ?

**My code**

```
public ActionResult GetCity(int idCountry)
{

    TravelEnterAdminTemplate.Models.LG.MyJsonResult myresult = new Models.LG.MyJsonResult();

        var citystable = db.Cities.Where(p => p.CountryId == idCountry).ToList();

        if (citystable != null)
        {
            myresult.Result = true;
            myresult.obj = citystable;

        }
        else
        {
            myresult.Result = false;
            myresult.message = "داده ای یافت نشد";
        }


    return Json(myresult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the error you are getting the data. There were 32 data in cities table . You just click on every node there the detail will visible

Comment: @ali I did not get you the purpose of "json should be returned".use IEnumerable <Cities> citystable instead of var citystable, it won't show you the json here but it will be accessible in the front end try it